# Clarification about injectivity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:{X\to Y}$ be a function.

Show:
$f$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow \exists \space h:{Y\to X} \ni h\circ f=id_X$.

If we have $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$. My problem is how can we have the function $h$? f is injective but not surjective this means that there might be values of $Y$ that don't correspond to anything in $X$. By the definition of a function h must map all values from $Y$ to $X$. How can I find $h\circ f=id_X$

I am thinking about restriction function here, $ h:{Y/{A}\to X}$ but the problem asks for $Y$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the axiom of choice ?

Comment: I haven't studied it formally.

Comment: The point is that you want to define $h$ as follows : If $y$ lies in the image of $f$ you define $h(y)$ to be the unique $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. Otherwise, you send $y$ just somewhere.

Comment: to x? I create create h as some sort of a characteristic function?

Comment: @Epsilon How is the axiom of choice involved?

Comment: You are right. I had sections of surjective functions in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exists $h\colon Y\to X$ such that $h\circ f=\mathit{id}_X$; if $f(a)=f(b)$, for $a,b\in X$, then
$$
h(f(a))=h(f(b))
$$
so $a=b$, by assumption. Hence $f$ is injective.

Suppose on the contrary that $f$ is injective and that $X$ is not empty. Let $x_0\in X$ and define $h\colon Y\to X$
$$
h(y)=\begin{cases}
x & \text{if $f(x)=y$ for some $x\in X$}\\[4px]
x_0 & \text{if $y\ne f(x)$ for all $x\in X$}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that this is a good definition of a function $h\colon Y\to X$, because the element $x$ in the first case is uniquely determined, being $f$ injective.

Can you show that $h\circ f=\mathit{id}_X$?

**Side notes**

1. The assumption that $X$ is not empty is essential
2. The axiom of choice is not relevant for the argument
3. If we identify $f$ with the set $\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$, then
   $$h=\{(f(x),x):x\in X\}\cup\{(y,x_0):y\in Y\setminus\operatorname{im}f\}$$

Comment: I understand the first part of the definition of $h(y)$ since we have f injective. How is $x_0$ chosen?

Comment: @Jeny In no special way: the hypothesis that $X\ne\emptyset$ provides an element. It can be *any* element of $X$.

Comment: Got it! I'm new with proofs and I am learning to grasp the concepts behind them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can define how $h$ works with those values $\alpha \in Y $ for which does not exists a $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=\alpha$ in this way: $h(\alpha)=x$ if $f(x)=\alpha$ and $h(\beta)=z \in X$ if $\not\exists x \in X \space ,f(x)=\beta.$
This function do what we want.